# How to change the base of URL in alias directory

Tags: apache, alias, base-url

I have to website are reside on two different servers. mainwebsite on server1 and subwebsite on server2 . the subwebsite must be accessed as a http://mainwebsite.com/subwebsite .

An alias for it is define on server1 . but the URLs on subwebsite aren't right. for example the link 'Home' with '/' url referes to 'http://mainwebsite.com' not 'http://mainwebsite.com/subwebsite' and the sessions also don't work because they are set to '/' .

Is the any configuration directive on apache that change the '/' to 'http://mainwebsite.com/subwebsite' ?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need something like this?

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ServerName www.mainserver.com
  # Proxy configuration
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /subdomain/ http://server2
  ProxyPassReverse /subdomain/ http://server1/subdomain/
</VirtualHost>
```

The outside world will see the site as it if was hosted on the same server. The mainserver will tell Apache to request everything under /subdomain to server2 and pass the response back to the client.